# jQuery - How to search $variable.val() contains a certain character

Tags: jquery

I have a code:

```
field_val = $(this).val();
```

I just need to check if field_val contains the character '%'.

like

```
  if(field_val:contains('%')){
    console_log(field_val);
    }
```

but this is undefined/not correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
var is_field_val = $(this).val().indexOf('%') != -1; //true or false

if (is_field_val) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
if(field_val.indexOf('%') != -1){
    console_log(field_val);
}
```

`$(this).val();` returns regular string, not jquery object or something like that, so there are no any special methods for it, only those available for string variables in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf():

```
if(field_val.indexOf('%') != -1)){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
field_val = "The string i am going to % check";

if (field_val.match("%")) {
     alert('Yes');
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something like  `if('$(this)[value^="%"]')` because it actually starts with %. Thanks everyone.